# Oracle SQL Return First & Last Value From Different Columns By Partition

Tags: sql, oracle

I need help with a query that will return a single record per partition in the below dataset. I used the DENSE_RANK to get the order and first/last position within each partition, but the problem is that I need to get a single record for each EMPLOYEE ITEM_ID combination which contains:

- MIN(START) which is date type with time
- SUM(DURATION) which is a number type signifying seconds of activity
- MIN ranked value from INIT_STATUS
- MAX ranked value from FIN_STATUS

Here is the initial data table, the same data table ordered with rank, and the desired result at the end (see image below):

Also, here is the code used to get the ordered table with rank values:

```
SELECT T.*,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY T.EMPLOYEE, T.ITEM_ID ORDER BY T.START) AS D_RANK
FROM TEST_DATA T
ORDER BY T.EMPLOYEE, T.ITEM_ID, T.START;
```

[image: Data Before & After]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `first/last` option to find statuses. The rest is classic aggregation:

```
select employee, min(start_), sum(duration),
       max(init_status) keep (dense_rank first order by start_),
       max(fin_status)  keep (dense_rank last  order by start_)
  from test_data t
  group by employee, item_id
  order by employee, item_id;
```

`start` is a reserved word, so I used `start_` for my test.

Comment: Thank you for solving this. I read the Oracle docs on FIRST/LAST and it states that the input should be a number type or be able to be implicitly converted to a number so I assumed the MAX/MIN function on a VARCHAR2 field would not work. I guess I should have tried it because I was on the right track.

Comment: Date, timestamp, varchar values are commonly used for sorting and they can by used here. We can say which timestamp or string is greater, which is first or last.